# Outputting nbsp; in Razor via variables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having a blank here.

I need to output "nbsp;" via a variable:

```
string strSpacer = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

So was trying:

```
@:strSpacer
```

Does not work, although I do get the following in the page source:

```
&amp;nbsp;
```

What do I need to do to resolve this please?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you're looking for `@Html.Raw(strSpacer)` See some more info about this function here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: is that  @Html.Raw(strSpacer);

Comment: Wait, that does not work in my MVC, strSpacer is not recognized

Comment: Ho ok sorry i just realized i am dumb, but your answer should contain the simplest thing : @Html.Raw("&nbsp")

Comment: @AntoinePelletier haha indeed, I used the variable in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - is to use the style in the HTML element:

```
<tr>
    <td width="1" style="white-space:nowrap">@board.X x @board.Y</td>
    <td width="1" style="white-space:nowrap">@board.Value.Name</td>
    <td>@board.Description</td>
</tr>
```